# Are feature importances from tree based models directly actionable for business?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, scikit-learn, cart, causality

If my response variable say is "has_repurchased" [0 or 1] and I have all customer level features.  Can I rank the features in order of importance from the random forest model and report them as whats most important to focus on for the business impact?

Forex: store rating, time taken for delivery, total_amount_spent, gender, age, lifestyle (working, college, kids etc.) are my features. And RF tells me store rating is most important in whether a customer has_repurchased. Can I frame strategies around prioritizing campaigns that improve store rating related initiatives?

OR is it that feature importance is only mathematical importance within a model but not actionable? Please eli5 as to why or why not?

Comment: Reviewing https://explained.ai/rf-importance/index.html will be helpful

Comment: Thank you!!! - Can I say that feature importances generated from Xgboost instead of Random forest also suffer from the same issue (the article only mentions random forest)?

Comment: I expect the same phenomenon is present in gradient boosted trees, but I haven't examined the issue closely.